# Rename several file with similar name by command line using regex

Tags: regex, rename, mv

I have 3 files named: test_1,test_2 and test_3. How can i use only 1 `mv` command to rename they become : TEST_1,TEST_2 and TEST_3? Thanks!

Comment: You can try to use the rename command that allows you to use Perl regular expressions.

Comment: You can use krename or total commander to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rename` script available then use:

```
rename 'y/[a-z]/[A-Z]/' test_*
```

Answer (score 0):

Given these files:

```
$ ls
Test_1  tesT_3  test 4  test_2
```

(note `test 4` with a space) You can use a splat loop like so:

```
$ for f in *; do mv -v "${f}"  "$(echo ${f} | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')"; done
Test_1 -> TEST_1
tesT_3 -> TEST_3
test 4 -> TEST 4
test_2 -> TEST_2
$ ls
TEST 4  TEST_1  TEST_2  TEST_3
```

It relies on using [tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) to translate lower to upper case which is LOCALE sensitive.

If you want more complete control, use perl or sed to substitute a regex pattern for your file names:

```
$ ls
test_1  test_2  test_3
$ for f in *; do mv -v "${f}"  "$(echo ${f} | perl -pe 's/([a-z])?(.*)/\U\1\E\2/')"; done 
test_1 -> Test_1
test_2 -> Test_2
test_3 -> Test_3
$ ls
Test_1  Test_2  Test_3
```

Comment: If i want to rename to Test_1, Test_2... How can i do? Thanks!